# Frame size issues in tKinter and PySimpleGUI

Tags: python, pysimplegui

I'm trying to create a 4-part display with a frame below it spanning both columns.  I have tried to do this in tKinter and now PySimpleGUI.  I can get it 'close' but not right.  When I insert placeholders for the displays the size for the frame is completely ignored.  I will insert my exact code for this so you can see that eventhough the frame size is identical in each frame (except the last one), the frames all display different sizes.
The frame sizes hold true until I add the object into the frame.

```
# Imports
import PySimpleGUI as sg

sg.theme('DarkGrey9')


#Global Values
global smoker
global probe
global req_smoker
global req_probe



#smoker will be coded to read the temperature of internal smoker probe
smoker = 180

#probe will be coded to read the temperature of meat probe
probe = 100

req_smoker = int(input("Enter Desired Smoker Temperature: "))

req_probe = int(input("Enter Desired Finish Temperature: "))




if smoker < req_smoker and probe < req_probe:
#activate heating element
    print("Heating")
elif smoker >= req_smoker and probe < req_probe:
#turn off heating element
    print("maintain heat")
elif probe >= req_probe:
    req_smoker = req_probe
    print("Your meat is done!")


col1 = sg.Column([
    [sg.Frame('Smoker Temperature', [[sg.Text("10", font=["Helvetica", 100], text_color="#FF0000", justification="center")],
                                     [sg.Text("Heat Status", font=[48], justification="center", )]], size=(200, 300))],

    [sg.Frame('Req_Smoker Temperature', [[sg.Text("200", font=["Helvetica", 150])]], size=(200, 300))]
                ])

col2 = sg.Column([
    [sg.Frame('Probe Temperature', [[sg.Text("300", font=["Helvetica", 120])]], size=(200,300))],

    [sg.Frame('Finish Temperature', [[sg.Text("40", font=["Helvetica", 180])]], size=(200, 300))]
                ])

col3 = sg.Column([
    [sg.Frame("Options", [[sg.Button('Data-log'), sg.Button("Close"), ]], element_justification="center", size=(500, 100))]
                ])



layout = [[col1, col2], [col3]]

window = sg.Window('Smoker Display', layout, grab_anywhere=True, )

while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    print(event, values)
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break



window.close()
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Option `size` not work for `sg.Frame` now, use option `size` of `sg.Column` which inside `sg.Frame` to set the size.

[image]

Demo code

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

sg.theme('DarkGrey9')
size = (300, 200)

column1 = [
    [sg.Text("10", font=("Helvetica", 50), text_color="#FF0000", justification="center")],
    [sg.Text("Heat Status", font=[48], justification="center", )]
]
column2 = [
    [sg.Text("300", font=["Helvetica", 100])]
]
column3 = [
    [sg.Text("200", font=["Helvetica", 120])]
]
column4 = [
    [sg.Text("40", font=["Helvetica", 150])]
]
column5 = [
    [sg.Button('Data-log'), sg.Button("Close")]
]

layout = [
    [sg.Frame('Smoker Temperature',     [[sg.Column(column1, size=size)]]),
     sg.Frame('Probe Temperature' ,     [[sg.Column(column2, size=size)]])],
    [sg.Frame('Req_Smoker Temperature', [[sg.Column(column3, size=size)]]),
     sg.Frame('Finish Temperature',     [[sg.Column(column4, size=size)]])],
    [sg.Frame('Options',                [[sg.Column(column5, size=size)]])],
]

window = sg.Window('Smoker Display', layout, grab_anywhere=True, )

while True:

    event, values = window.read()
    print(event, values)
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break

window.close()
```

[Update] `sg.Column`

- `justification` set justification for the Column itself. Note entire row containing the Column will be affected
- `element_justification` All elements inside the Column will have this justification 'left', 'right', 'center' are valid values

There's something important for `justification` and `element_justification`, it mean alignment to element with max width.

All frames or columns here with same size

- `justification` work but look all the same for same size.
- `element_justification` work but aligned to element with max width. For example, "10" will be aligned to right side of "Heat Status" if you set `element_justification='right'`, not all elements aligned right to column. (The state now)

Comment: Do you know why the justification command is being ignored in column1?  Is that something I'll just have to put up with, or is it fixable?

Comment: Updated as above.